# how to multiple Aggregate from XMLTYPE field within 1 sql?

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle

Belows are the xml data stored in a field call xmldoc with data type XMLTYPE and the pattern are stored in each record.

The first row(record) of the xmldoc field should be:

```
<cdata>
<r> <year>2009</year>
<month>Jan</month>
<day>1</day>
<data>1180</data>
</r>
</cdata>
```

and the second row of the xmldoc field should be:

```
<cdata>
<r>
<year>2009</year>
<month>Jan</month>
<day>2</day>
<data>1280</data>
</r>
</cdata>
```

and the belowed xml datas are also modified into the upper example (each data stored in a row record in xmldoc field and embedded a 'cdata' root element.)

```
<r>
<year>2009</year>
<month>Jan</month>
<day>3</day>
<data>1380</data>
</r>
<r>
<year>2009</year>
<month>Feb</month>
<day>1</day>
<data>2180</data>
</r>
<r>
<year>2009</year>
<month>Feb</month>
<day>2</day>
<data>2280</data>
</r>
<r>
<year>2009</year>
<month>Feb</month>
<day>3</day>
<data>2380</data>
</r>
<r>
<year>2010</year>
<month>Jan</month>
<day>1</day>
<data>1181</data>
</r>
<r>
<year>2010</year>
<month>Jan</month>
<day>2</day>
<data>1281</data>
</r>
<r>
<year>2010</year>
<month>Jan</month>
<day>3</day>
<data>1381</data>
</r>
<r>
<year>2010</year>
<month>Feb</month>
<day>1</day>
<data>2181</data>
</r>
<r>
<year>2010</year>
<month>Feb</month>
<day>2</day>
<data>2281</data>
</r>
<r>
<year>2010</year>
<month>Feb</month>
<day>3</day>
<data>2381</data>
</r>
```

now, i use this sql:

```
SELECT X.year, x.month, sum(x.data) as sumMonth
FROM xmltest, 
XMLTABLE ('$d/cdata/r' passing xmldoc as "d" 
   COLUMNS 
  year integer path 'year',
  month varchar(3) path 'month',
  day varchar(2) path 'day',
  data float path 'data'
  ) AS X
group by x.year, x.month
```

order by x.year, x.month

i can get the sum of 'data' by each month in each year from this sql and the question i would like to know is how to display the sum of each year after the column sumMonth and just modify this sql but **not use two or more sql** to get the aggregation of month and year in same time.

the output maybe like this:

```
year month  sumMonth sumYear
2009  Jan    3840     10680
2009  Feb    6840     10680
2010  Jan    3843     10686
2010  Feb    6843     10686
```

thanks everyone gave me the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407):

```
SELECT v.YEAR, v.MONTH, v.sumMonth, 
       SUM(v.sumMonth) over(PARTITION BY v.YEAR) sumYear
  FROM (SELECT X.YEAR, x.MONTH, SUM(x.data) AS sumMonth
           FROM xmltest,
                XMLTABLE('$d/cdata/r' passing xmldoc AS "d" 
                  COLUMNS YEAR INTEGER path 'year',
                          MONTH VARCHAR(3) path 'month',
                          DAY VARCHAR(2) path 'day',
                          data FLOAT path 'data') AS X
          GROUP BY x.YEAR, x.MONTH) v
```

Comment: thanks your reply, but it return an error code: [SQL Error: No more data to read from socket]...is there any idea to fix it?

Comment: This looks like an I/O error, not a query error. Do you get the same error message if you replace `xmltest` by something simple such as `(SELECT XMLTYPE('<cdata><r><year>2009</year><month>Jan</month><day>1</day><data>1180</data></r></cdata>') xmldoc FROM dual))` ?